# OpenCV counting number of pixels in a horizontal line

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I wish to find number of white pixels in every row of binary image. And if that count is greater than 90, I wish to delete the entire row by changing each pixel value in that row to 0. The code that I wrote is not working. And apparently, I am getting the same binary image at output.
Please help me out in fixing the problem. BTW, am using openCV 2.0.

```
using namespace std;

double a = 15;

double b = 255;

Mat I1;

int main(int argv, char **argc)

{

    cv: Mat I = imread("abc.bmp");

    if (I.empty())

    {

        std::cout << "!!! Failed imread(): image not found" << std::endl;

    }

    threshold(I, I1, a, b, THRESH_BINARY);


    int r = I.rows;

    int c = I.cols;

    for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)

    {

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)

        {

            if (I1.at<uchar>(j, i) == 255)

                count = count + 1;

        }

        if (count > 90)

        {

            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)

                I1.at<uchar>(j, i) = 0;

        }

    }
    namedWindow("Display window", 0);// Create a window for display.

    imshow("Display window", I1);


    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the image after thresholding. Can it be that count is never>90 ?

Comment: The image size am working with is 4096*3072. I have developed the similar code in matlab and wish to implement it in openCV

Comment: There looks no problem with the code. Post the input image, binary image and the output image, if possible.

Comment: Post input/thresholded/output please. Use an image hosting platform if you dont have enough reputation to upload images on SO

Comment: Note that jet47 is right in his answer, that cv::threshold needs a grayscale image as input to achieve expected behaviour!!

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img674/7509/57jaH3.jpg - input image
http://imageshack.com/a/img661/3727/vSg6ZV.jpg - binary image
http://imageshack.com/a/img674/4363/HiOa2D.jpg -output image. In the output image, only left part is modified. But, lines on right part should have got removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default `imread` returns 3 channel BGR image. If you want to load grayscale/binary image use `cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` parameter:

```
cv::Mat I = cv::imread("abc.bmp", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: cv::Mat I = imread("abc.bmp",0); helped..Thank you very much :-)